# What does this error message in the Identity Server logs mean?

Tags: identity-server

I have a Sitecore 9.1.1 instance that I am trying to configure to use ADFS 2016 for Federated Authentication.  I am following the instructions from this blog post - https://blog.istern.dk/2019/05/15/sitecore-9-1-identityserver-on-premise-ad-via-adfs/.  When I click on the new Login With ADFS button I get a Chrome error screen that says the Identity Server is "currently unable to handle this request" HTTP 500 error.  When I look in the Identity Server logs I see the following, but I have absolutely no idea what it means or how to troubleshoot it.

> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.3688010-04:00 [INF] (Sitecore STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2)
>   Executing action method
>   "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLogin
>   (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" with arguments (["adfs",
>   "/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=Sitecore&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20sitecore.profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D71mbGM-gg9b4GNwAXgLZ48zBeDsbQ-MphZ8cP0Rq1ni3YoaIwA7W-QBcOvjQyr91SX0VmMFVEHC9ecu8WVCJfvOooVTqkW1apNIHN3aBaCEp0SEuAtB5djhpNOOU4_ggkY5qqJA4ibSstUWwMUAEh9iNNGhxkDTdKj0olNk4wmHXgQE00R_SAO0lMvvpmrFy-ebwJ2DN5khoI9JbSXT76Q&nonce=636955241322185780.MTZlYzhiMjYtOGM3Mi00NDI1LTg4NjUtNmMyNWMyMWExYjJmMTE3OTQyNjAtYTU5Ni00YzdkLTg4ZjktNmNjOTQ4YjcyMmYw&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkellogg91.local%2Fidentity%2Fsignin&sc_account_prefix=sitecore%5C&x-client-SKU=ID_NET451&x-client-ver=5.2.2.0"])
>   - Validation state: Valid
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.3689117-04:00 [INF] (Sitecore STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2) Executed action method
>   "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLogin
>   (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)", returned result
>   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult" in 0.0458ms.
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.3689844-04:00 [INF] (Sitecore STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2)
>   Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (["adfs"]).
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.7336916-04:00 [INF] (Sitecore STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2)
>   Executed action
>   "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLogin
>   (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)" in 365.7107ms
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.7341497-04:00 [ERR] (Sitecore STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2)
>   Connection id ""0HLNBD6RJUVVQ"", Request id
>   ""0HLNBD6RJUVVQ:00000004"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to
>   obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the
>   'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.
>   ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 1, position 1.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean
>   hasConverter)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String
>   address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties
>   properties)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties
>   properties)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext
>   context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsyncTFilter,TFilterAsync
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService
>   events)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication1
>   application)
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.7366113-04:00 [DBG] (Sitecore
>   STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2) Connection id ""0HLNBD6RJUVVQ"" completed keep alive
>   response.
>
> 2019-06-07T13:08:54.7366776-04:00 [INF] (Sitecore
>   STS/VSLT-D3CV4H2) Request finished in 369.7736ms 500

EDIT: here is the XML configuration file for this instance. It is located at [Identity Server Root]/sitecoreruntime/production/sitecore/[ClientName].ADFS/Config/[ClientName].ADFS.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <ExternalIdentityProviders>
  <IdentityProviders>
  <ADFS type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.IdentityProvider, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
    <AuthenticationScheme>adfs</AuthenticationScheme>
    <DisplayName>Login with My Custom ADFS</DisplayName>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ClientId>1234</ClientId>
    <Authority>[full URL for ADFS endpoint goes here]</Authority>
    <MetaAddress>[full URL for ADFS metadata goes here]</MetaAddress>
    <ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation1 type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
        <SourceClaims>
          <Claim1 type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
        </SourceClaims>
        <NewClaims>
          <Claim1 type="name" />
        </NewClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation1>
      <ClaimsTransformation2 type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
        <SourceClaims>
          <Claim1 type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
        </SourceClaims>
        <NewClaims>
          <Claim1 type="email" />
        </NewClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation2>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
  </ADFS>
  </IdentityProviders>
</ExternalIdentityProviders>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Can you post the configuration?? It seems like some invalids configuration

Comment: You can try to set IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; in ConfigureServices to enable viewing of PII logs to see more details error message.

Comment: Thomas Stern - which configuration should I post here? /Config/production/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml? /sitecoreruntime/production/sitecore/myProvider/Config? Some other config file on the Identity Server?

Comment: x3mxray - where can I set that to true?  Is that in a config file somewhere?

Comment: The configuration for the on-prem adfs module

Comment: Ok.  I am guessing that what you mean is this file:  [Identity Server Root]\sitecoreruntime\production\sitecore\ClientName.ADFS\ClientName.ADFS.xml - right?

Comment: Yes that file :)... Okay seems  good enoug. You are sure you can reach the adfs server and login ? Does the error happen before or after you're redirected to the ADFS server ?

Comment: I am never redirected to the ADFS server. It happens when I click the custom login button

Comment: okay then the error is most likely because you cant reach your  adfs server ie. the url added in the Authority setting

Comment: DId you ever figure it out? I'm currently having the same issue

Comment: No I never figured it out. We changed from ADFS to Azure AD.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your identity server is not being able to either connect to your sitecore instance or the connection string of identity server is not properly set.

To fix this open Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml within your server and make sure that the connection string is a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when in the file `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`

This url is not set to a url that the server can reach, and is the url that the identity server is running on.

`<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://SitecoreIdentityServerHost" />`